# Oracle SQL Developer Date Diff between Two Dates With Different Formats

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been running into a weird issue while using SQL DEVELOPER, I have two dates that I would like to get the difference between; however, I have been getting inaccurate results...

I have:

```
 column1 with the date 03-Aug-2016
 column2 with the date 08-July-2016
```

when using `to_date` function with the following:

`to_date(column1, 'dd-mon-yyyy')` ==> the date is displayed as `03-Aug-2016`

but column2 is different story as it gives the following:

`to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-yyyy')` ==> the date is displayed as **10-July-2016**

but when using `to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-RR')` ==> the date is displayed as **08-July-2016**

and when I use the following in my query I get a weird number

`to_date(column1, 'dd-mon-yyyy') - to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-RR')` ==> **-730463**

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: what is the datatype of column1 and column2? . If it's already date, you should not be applying `to_date` over it.

Comment: Both are dates; however, when I apply the subtraction it gives -730463.4

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a column which is already a date using [**TO_DATE**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

> `TO_DATE` converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2
>   datatype to a value of DATE datatype.

Since you have provided the first argument as a `DATE` type, Oracle will implicitly convert it to a string using your session's NLS parameters.

So,`to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-yyyy')` is equivalent to

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-07-08', ( -- 08-July-2016
     SELECT value
     FROM nls_session_parameters
     WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' 
) ),'dd-mon-yyyy')
FROM dual
```

**`10-jul-16`**  is what you are seeing from the above(again due to your session's NLS format), but it is actually **`10-jul-0016`** and not **`10-Jul-2016`**

Whereas the expression `to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-RR')` is evaluating to  **`08-jul-2016`**. This is because your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `'DD-MON-RR'` if I'm not wrong.

So, the weird number you see is the difference between the two dates.

If you want to confirm, simply run this. i.e. subtracting date literals as pure dates without conversion.

```
SELECT DATE '0016-08-03' - DATE '2016-07-08' FROM dual;--  -730461
```

Comment: Thanks! I see, and I tried subtracting directly since they are already in date format; however, the number still is not shown in days.

Comment: @user2597012 : What do you see then?

Comment: I see -730463, that is what is displayed

Comment: Ok, then that means it is stored incorrectly ?. what do you see when you run `select to_char(column1,'yyyy-mm-dd') , to_char(column2,'yyyy-mm-dd') ..`? Also,  what's the o/p from `SELECT value
     FROM nls_session_parameters
     WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'`

Comment: I get 0016-08-01 and 2016-07-08.

Comment: and the output is: DD-MON-RR

Comment: @user2597012 : Exactly. Fix your data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181352/discussion-between-user2597012-and-kaushik-nayak).

Comment: Can you please give an example? as I have tried to cast but with no luck so far.

Comment: @user2597012 : I'm not sure what else do you want to know. Your data is stored incorrectly in the table. You should first fix it. This question answered and gave you one of the reasons why the data may be wrongly displayed. Similar thing might have happened while inserting/updating the value in that column. If you think this answers your question, please accept the answer. Ask another question if you want to know something else or stuck in proceeding further given this data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the

```
to_date(column1, 'dd-mon-RRRR') - to_date(column2, 'dd-mon-RRRR')
```

Alway use RRRR when you are working on dates. this will ensure to have the dates format as per y2k.

If this doesn't solve your issue, Please share the column types you are having for these Column1 and Column2

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it and it gave me 24 days (where it should be 26) but as column1 result was 1-AUG-2016 instead of 3rd. and both columns have "DATE" and datatype.

Comment: if both your columns are a date then simple use Column1-column2 why to recast these to dates. If you want to left out time then use Trunc(column1)-trunc(column2)